# What happens to FK if I drop a table with set foreignkey_checks=0 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

When I drop some tables with `set foreign_key_checks=0`, then are the constraints(like foreign keys) on those tables also dropped? Or we will end up with some orphan constraints, that are not related to any tables at all?

Answer (score 1):

No it only drop the table with the triggers on it 
other tables views remains

Comment: thanks for reply.<br> actually i meant that if tables are dropped after foreign_key_checks is set to 0 what happens to their foreign keys and other constraints. are they dropped too?